# Use sed to remove line from json array and comma from previous line

Tags: json, bash, sed

I've been trying to use sed to remove agent4 as well as the comma after agent 3 (So it stays valid json). I originally tried `sed 's/\"agent4\"/` which then morphed into `sed 's/,\n\s+\"agent4\"/` but I found out that sed reads individual lines so I haven't been able to progress from here.

It has to use sed.

```
{
  "environments": {
    "default": {
      "machines": {
        "dev-machine": {
          "agents": [
            "agent1",
            "agent2",
            "agent3",
            "agent4"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `sed` is the wrong tool for this job. *Why* does it have to be `sed`?

Comment: ... because jq isn't available on most *nix systems by default and sed is.

Answer (score 0):

Using a proper JSON tool like `jq`:

```
% jq '.environments.default.machines["dev-machine"].agents |= .[:-1]' tmp.json
{
  "environments": {
    "default": {
      "machines": {
        "dev-machine": {
          "agents": [
            "agent1",
            "agent2",
            "agent3"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command,

```
$ sed '/3\"/ s/,//g; N; s/\"agent4\"/,/' data.json
```

Reference: [How can I use sed to replace a multi-line string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string)